# Laravel @extends second parameter array explanation

Tags: laravel

Question:
I am new to laravel,

`@extends('layouts.app', ['page' => 'Receipts', 'pageSlug' => 'receipts', 'section' => 'inventory'])` 
I understand @extends first parameter 'layouts.app', but what does the second parameter do?

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel `@extend`  second parameter just to pass data in another blade.

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['title' => 'Page Title'])
```

This is how the second parameter works in laravel main layout

```
 <title>App Name - {{ ucfirst($title) }}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending layouts.blade.php file, you have to look into the file. In layouts.blade.php you need variables such as $page, $pageSlug, $section to be defined. So you are defining/passing each variable.

Like Python
`page = Receipts, pageSlug = receipts, section = inventory`

equals

`'page' => 'Receipts', 'pageSlug' => 'receipts', 'section' => 'inventory'`